# I am not able to place an order with new customer also in magento 1 Stripe Payment Gateway

Tags: stripe-payments, magento-1.9

I am working on a payment method in Magento 1 Stripe Payment Gateway but for some issue, I am not able to place an order for the new customer also and for the already created customer can anyone guide me to the solution 
https://prnt.sc/s5piuq

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse a PaymentMethod you need to attach it to a customer: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

If you don't it gets consumed when you charge it and can't be used again.